# Check field on referenced entity to hide page title

Tags: panels, entities

I am using Fieldable Panel Panes for editors to be able to create panes that include an image, title description and link plus the ability to attach this pane to any content node through an entity reference. This gets nicely formatted in a template to format as a feature image on top of the page.

Problem: in some cases the feature image with title and description should replace the general page title, in others it should not.

I am considering to add a field to the pane that reads "Hide page title". If the editor ticks that field, I want to hide it in my page template like so:

```
<?php if ($show_title && $title): ?><h1 class="title" id="page-title"><?php print $title; ?></h1><?php endif; ?>
```

I am trying to check the field value in preprocess_node like this:

`function clf_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['type']=='panel') {
$show_title=field_get_items('node',$variables['node'],'field_featur_remove_page_title');
  }
}`

My problem is that this returns nothing as the field is not attached to the actual node, but a fieldable panel pane with an entity reference to the node.

What is the correct call to get the value of the field from the pane?

Thanks, J.